# Deleted Message history on my iPhone is still on Apple Watch

Tags: sms

My partner has a message on his Apple Watch but denying it came from him.  I searched his iPhone and couldn’t find the original message.  Could this message have came from his Apple Watch only or would it still show up on his phone?  If he deleted the message from his phone should it automatically delete from his Watch. Can a hacker send a text from his Watch only.  I’m confused as to why it’s on his Apple Watch but not on his iPhone.

Comment: Probably deleted it from his phone but not his watch.

Comment: Yeh that’s what I said.  If his phone or watch was compromised could it be possible for a message to be sent and only show on his Watch?  And if his phone had been compromised and a message sent I’m guessing this would show up on his bill?  Thankyou for responding 